# Parsing a string composed of multiple JSON objects run together

Tags: python

Given a string like this:

```
str= "{"Months": "12", "details":["id": "a123a", "text": "something, somethingelse, againwiththesomething", "value": "-2536"}, {"comment": "something", "value": "6500", "id": "abc123"}], "Date": "2017-12-31"}
{"Months": "9", "details":["id": "foo", "text": "something, somethingelse, againwiththesomething", "value": "-656"}, {"comment": "something", "value": "9800", "id": "bar"}], "Date": "2017-12-31"}
{"Months": "12", "details":["id": "woo", "text": "something, somethingelse, againwiththesomething", "value": "3776"}, {"comment": "something", "value": "600", "id": "tar"}], "Date": "2017-12-31"}"
```

You will notice there are 3 separate Json structures in there, but they are not separated by a `,`.  Not that there could be any number of JSON parts, in the example i have only listed 3 but there could be any number.

Is there a way to correctly parse this in python and output it all as valid comma separated JSON ?

I have tried:

```
decoder = JSONDecoder()
pos = 0
while True:
    result, pos = decoder.raw_decode(str, pos)
    print(result)
```

as well as:

```
result = json.loads(str)
```

but neither will work.

Is this possible with a Python function?

Comment: Are these json objects always on their own line like your example?

Comment: It seems they are separated by a newline char, just split on `\n` no ?

Comment: If there are newlines between the JSON Objects, what you have is something in [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format and the simple way to deal with it is to call `json.loads()` on each _line_ of the input. There's also a third-party module named [jsonlines](https://pypi.org/project/jsonlines/) that you could try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your example is not valid json structure (probably it should be list of dictionaries) and there is a typo:

```
 "details":["id": "a123a",
```

if you fix that you can try to do something like:

```
import json

fixed_str = """{"Months": "12", "details":[{"id": "a123a", "text": "something, somethingelse, againwiththesomething", "value": "-2536"}, {"comment": "something", "value": "6500", "id": "abc123"}], "Date": "2017-12-31"}
{"Months": "9", "details":[{"id": "foo", "text": "something, somethingelse, againwiththesomething", "value": "-656"}, {"comment": "something", "value": "9800", "id": "bar"}], "Date": "2017-12-31"}
{"Months": "12", "details":[{"id": "woo", "text": "something, somethingelse, againwiththesomething", "value": "3776"}, {"comment": "something", "value": "600", "id": "tar"}], "Date": "2017-12-31"}"""

result = [json.loads(x) for x in fixed_str.splitlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to replace `}{` (the "gap" between the two objects) with `}, {`.  Then you can wrap the whole thing in `[]` and parse it as a list.

```
import re
import json

data = re.sub(r'}\s*?{', '},{', str)
result = json.loads('[' + data + ']')
```